# Considering the coordinates $x = \sinh u \sin v$, $y = \sinh u \cos v$, how do I show that these coordinates are orthogonal?

Tags: calculus

I know that orthogonal means meeting at right angles, but I'm unsure about how to go about computing it.

Also, how do I find $\nabla f$ for these coordinates?

Comment: What is their inner product?

Answer (score 0):

Given coordinates 
$$(x,y) = (\sinh u \sin v, \sinh u \cos v)$$
Calculate scale factors/metrics
$$h_u=\sqrt{x_u^2+y_u^2}=\sqrt{\cosh^2 u\sin^2 v+\cosh^2 u\cos^2 v}=\cosh u
$$
$$h_v=\sqrt{x_v^2+y_v^2}=\sqrt{\sinh^2 u\cos^2 v+\sinh^2 u(-\sin v)^2}=\sinh u
$$
thus $$\nabla= \left(\frac1{h_u}\frac{\partial }{\partial x},\frac1{h_v}\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)=
\left(\frac1{\cosh u}\frac{\partial }{\partial x},\frac1{\sinh u}\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)$$